# Is there an equivalent of differential geometry for infinite dimensional spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request, soft-question, reference-works

Differential and (Semi/Pseudo-)Riemannian geometry provide a framework for doing calculus on finite dimensional manifolds and have applications in physics (general relativity) and dynamical systems analysis (e.g. control theory). I've wondered how much work has been done to develop a calculus on infinite dimensional manifolds to aid in, say, bifurcation analysis for PDEs like the bifurcation problems in continuum mechanics as discussed in chapter 7 of Marsden and Hughes' *Mathematical Foundations of Elasticity*. Patrolling Google Scholar or Web of Science has not been enlightening in whetting my curiosity. I usually find references that leave me unsure if they're on topic or, if I can glean that they do seem to touch on this topic, they are beyond my current skill set to gather any understanding or sense of the field.

Apologies if it seems like my intuitions are off on what is and isn't possible or what has and hasn't been done in these fields. I'm more of an applied mathematician in training, but I'd like to use more geometry in my work on solid mechanics and other PDE analysis/simulation problems because, well, it's beautiful.

Comment: One can replace $\Bbb R^n$ in the definition of a smooth manifold by a fixed Banach space $X$ and deal with manifolds modeled on $X$. Most theorems still hold in this setting. Lang's *Differentiable Manifolds* book comes to mind.

Comment: I'm aware of *Differentiable Manifolds* though I've not worked through it. If most theorems still hold, can we do calculus on Banach manifolds? Can functionals be optimized or computed them? Are there canonical examples of Banach manifolds whose geometry can be characterized? i.e. are there differentiable Banach manifolds that have the some equivalent of a "parametrized" embedding as one might have for a hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Calculus on Banach manifolds, yes. Optimizing functionals, yes. Embeddings of Banach manifolds, yes. I'm not an expert on these topics myself, but the thing about Lang's book is that the math is very clean and mostly coordinate free. He also talks about Banach vector bundles and things of the sort.

Comment: Just do not try to define Ricci or scalar curvature.